# Python Tkinter - Name is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

Code:

```
def createLetters(frame, startX, startY, width, height, spacing):

    alphabet = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", 
                "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", 
                "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]

    def letterAction(letter):
        letter.destroy()

    for i in range(0, 26):

        if (i >= 9 and i <= 17):
            y = startY +  height + 2 * spacing
            x = startX + ((width + spacing) * (i - 9))

        elif (i >= 17):
            y = startY + 2 * height + 3 * spacing
            x = (width + spacing) / 2 + startX + ((width + spacing) * (i - 18))

        elif (i <= 8):
            y = startY + spacing
            x = startX + ((width + spacing) * i)

        exec(alphabet[i] + " = Button(" + frame + ", text = '" + alphabet[i] + "', command = letterAction(" + alphabet[i] + "))")
        exec(alphabet[i] + ".place(x = " + str(x) + ", y = " + str(y) + ", width = " + str(width) + ", height = " + str(height) + ")")
```

Error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1442, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "E:\Hangman\hangmanTk.py", line 106, in playScreen
    createLetters("playFrame", 175, 250, 50, 50, 0)
  File "E:\Hangman\hangmanTk.py", line 95, in createLetters
    exec(alphabet[i] + " = Button(" + frame + ", text = '" + alphabet[i] + "', command = letterAction(" + alphabet[i] + "))")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'A' is not defined
```

I'm attempting to create multiple tkinter buttons with a loop. I can create the buttons fine but i can't seem to create callbacks for them. When ever i try, it tells me that the variables that i use for the buttons are not defined. I tried adding "exec("global " + alphabet[i])" above where i defined the buttons but that didn't change anything.

Comment: `import string; alphabet = list(string.ascii_uppercase)` would be a lot less painful

Comment: For that matter, there's no reason to have a list instead of a string in the first place, since all he needs to do is index it. (And looping over `enumerate` would make it even simpler.)

Comment: What does the `enumerate` function do with strings? I can't find any examples of it being used with a string.

Comment: @guney98: The same thing it does with any other iterable. It's easier to show than to explain, so just fire up your interpreter and type this: `print(list(enumerate('abc')))`

Comment: `place` is a very odd choice. Is there a specific reason you're using it instead of `grid`?

Comment: @BryanOakley It's just personal preference. I like being able to set the coordinates by typing their x and y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Using `exec` is almost always the wrong way to do it, no matter what "it" is.](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-evalexec-is-bad.html)

[And creating variables dynamically is almost always the wrong thing to do.](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html)

And your problems getting this to work are a perfect illustration of why.

---

Just create a `dict` mapping names to buttons:

```
buttons = {}

# ...

letter = alphabet[i]
buttons[letter] = Button(frame, text = letter, command = letterAction(letter))
buttons[letter].place(x = x, y = y, width = width, height = height)
```

If you really want to dump the `dict` into `locals()` (or, similarly, `self.__dict__` or `globals()` or …), that's trivial. But you don't. The only place you need to use the variable is in your `letterAction` function. So:

```
def createLetters(frame, startX, startY, width, height, spacing):

    alphabet = string.ascii_uppercase
    buttons = {}

    def letterAction(letter):
        buttons[letter].destroy()

    for i, letter in enumerate(alphabet):

        if (i >= 9 and i <= 17):
            y = startY +  height + 2 * spacing
            x = startX + ((width + spacing) * (i - 9))

        elif (i >= 17):
            y = startY + 2 * height + 3 * spacing
            x = (width + spacing) / 2 + startX + ((width + spacing) * (i - 18))

        elif (i <= 8):
            y = startY + spacing
            x = startX + ((width + spacing) * i)

        buttons[letter] = Button(frame, text = letter, command = letterAction(letter))
        buttons[letter].place(x = x, y = y, width = width, height = height)
```

---

But notice that this does the wrong thing. `command = letterAction(letter)`—whether you run it directly, or via `exec`—is going to call `letterAction(letter)` now, destroying the button before you even create it, and returning `None`, which you'll then set as the `command`.

You need `lambda: letterAction(letter)` or `partial(letterAction, letter)` to fix this.

Plus, you can't write code to pass the button variable itself to `letter`, either now or later, because the variable doesn't exist yet. You have to pass the *letter*, as a string, as I did above.

---

But really, if you think about it, you don't need these button variables at all—whether in a `dict` or otherwise. You just need a way to bind each button as its own callback's target, right? There are a number of ways to do this, but the obvious one is a class, either inheriting or delegating to `Button` (or, in this case, neither, since you don't need to use it as a button, or even remember it, after creation).

While we're at it, let's remove some extraneous parens and such that just make things harder to read and fix the problem that `17` seems to belong in two different groups…

```
class SelfDestructiveButton(object):
    def __init__(self, frame, letter, x, y, width, height):
        self.button = Button(frame, text=letter, command=self.command)
        self.button.place(x=x, y=y, width=width, height=height)
    def command(self):
        self.button.destroy()

def createLetters(frame, startX, startY, width, height, spacing):
    for i, letter in enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase):
        if 9 <= i <= 17:
            y = startY +  height + 2 * spacing
            x = startX + ((width + spacing) * (i - 9))
        elif i > 17:
            y = startY + 2 * height + 3 * spacing
            x = (width + spacing) / 2 + startX + ((width + spacing) * (i - 18))
        else:
            y = startY + spacing
            x = startX + ((width + spacing) * i)
        SelfDestructiveButton(frame, letter, x, y, width, height)
```

It might be even clearer with `if 'J' <= letter <= 'R'`, because it's the letters rather than the numbers that you're going to see while debugging it.

Answer (score 0):

The string in your first call to `exec` evaluates to:

```
"A = Button(<frame>, text = 'A', command = letterAction(A))"
```

You are therefore referencing `A` (the name) before having defined it. I'm guessing you forgot the single quotes around the second `alphabet[i]`:

```
exec(alphabet[i] + " = Button(" + frame + ", text = '" + alphabet[i] + "', command = letterAction('" + alphabet[i] + "'))")
```

Note this would call `letterAction('A')`, i.e. `'A'.destroy()`, which will throw an `AttributeError` since strings have no `destroy()` method. What is `letterAction` supposed to achieve?

Comment: Maybe the buttons are intended to destroy themselves? In this case, `A` (the button itself) is no yet created, and `letterAction` should return the `destroy` method, not invoke it.

Comment: @tobias_k Or perhaps use [`functools.partial()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) on the `letterAction` function. Either way `A` needs to be defined first though.

Comment: There's no way to make this work without using the button name _as a string_—either `lambda: letterAction('A')` or `partial(letterAction, 'A')`. Which means that `letterAction` has to look it up in `locals()`. (Of course it's really not a local, but a closure variable… but `locals()[letter]` will work.)